# Are HTML <cite> Tags Allowed in Lists?

Tags: html, citations

Are HTML <cite> tags is permitted in lists? Specifically, in lists of works by an author, as might appear on a biography page.

Some documentation says that  tags are allowed in "palpable" content, and lists seem to meet that definition.

Are the following examples valid uses of <cite>?

A list of book titles:

```
<p>His novels include:</p>
<ul>
<li><cite>A Sunny Childhood</cite> (New York: Publisher Name, 1970)</li>
<li><cite>High School Daze</cite> (Chicago, Illinois: Publisher Name, 1970)</li>
</ul>
```

A list of poem titles:

```
<p>His poetry includes:</p>
<ul>
<li><cite>Ode to an Oven</cite> (New York: Good Housekeeping, April 13, 1970), page 3</li>
<li><cite>The Old Schoolhouse</cite> (Chicago, Illinois: Chicago Tribune, November, 1970), p 4</li>
</ul>
```

If  tags can't appear in lists, how does one represent a list
of an author's works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML Citation element (`<cite>`) is used to describe a reference to a cited creative work, and must include the title of that work. The reference may be in an abbreviated form according to context-appropriate conventions related to citation metadata.

According to MDN it is permitted with any element which supports [Pharsing Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content).

Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/cite)

It is generally shown by most browsers in Italics. There is no restriction on its use in lists.

Answer (score 3):

There's an easy way to find out: Look at [MDN's documentation for `li`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li). On that page, there's a  box that says

> **Permitted content: [Flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content).**

That link takes you to the definition on "flow content" and includes a list of tags that are considered "flow content". `<cite>` is in that list.

Comment: Thanks for the quick turnaround!